# Copying secrets To Azure Key Vault from Hashicorp Vault

Tags: powershell, terraform, devops, azure-keyvault, hashicorp-vault

I need to populate my **Azure Key Vault** with the secrets available in **HashiCorp Vault**, for which I am looking for a best possible way. One thing I feel is using **PowerShell** it can be done but I am not getting any right reference or sample to follow. **Terraform** could also be a way.

Please share if any sample available to achieve the same.

Thanks

Comment: You can try using the Golang API for Vault - https://github.com/hashicorp/vault/tree/main/api

Comment: Did you happen to check this? https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/key-management-secrets